# tv remote in flutter, is it possible to make tv remote in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

is it possible to make tv remote in flutter?

I want to build tv remote in flutter which can connect with any tv using Bluetooth or WIFI connection.

Comment: My TV in my living room only uses Infrared for its report, no Wifi or Bluetooth... so your aim to control "any TV" isn't really doable.

Answer (score 1):

### For IR

You can use `ir_sensor_plugin` for sending IR Commands.

```dart
// Eg code for sending ok button for LG tv
Future<void> okButton() async {
  const String okPattern =
      '0000 006C 0022 0002 015B 00AD 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0041 0016 0016 0016 0041 0016 05F7 015B 0057 0016 0E6C';
  await IrSensorPlugin.transmitString(pattern: okPattern);
}
```

You can get IR commands for each device from [this](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/samsung/tv_functions/) website

### For upnp supported device

You can use [`upnp`](https://pub.dev/packages/upnp/install) package, refer [this](https://github.com/aelshamy/flutter_samsung_remote) repositoryy

Comment: and what about the connection between the app and target device